# How to plot data from csv for specific date and time using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have written a python  program to get data from csv using pandas and plot the data using matplotlib. My code is below with result:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
headers = ['Sensor Value','Date','Time']
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV',parse_dates=     {"Datetime" : [1,2]},names=headers)
#pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
#df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['Date'],r['Time']),)
print (df)

#f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
df.plot(x='Datetime',y='Sensor Value',) # figure.gca means "get current axis"
plt.title('Title here!', color='black')
plt.tight_layout()
plt._show()
```

[image]

Now as  you can see the x-axis looks horrible. How can I plot the x-axis for a single date and time interval so that it does not looks like overlapping each other? I have stored both date and time as one column in my dataframe.

My Dataframe looks like this:

```
                       Datetime  Sensor Value
0     2017/02/17  19:06:17.188             2
1     2017/02/17  19:06:22.360            72
2     2017/02/17  19:06:27.348            72
3     2017/02/17  19:06:32.482            72
4     2017/02/17  19:06:37.515            74
5     2017/02/17  19:06:42.580            70
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Hacky way

Try this:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.xticks(rotation = 90)
```

It will rotate the labels by 90 degrees, thus eliminating overlap.

#### Cleaner way

Check out [this link](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/recipes.html#fixing-common-date-annoyances) which describes how to use `fig.autofmt_xdate()` and let matplotlib pick the best way to format your dates.

#### Pandas way

Use [`to_datetime()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alRFj.png) and `set_index` with `DataFrame.plot()`:

```
df.Datetime=pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df.set_index('Datetime')
df['Sensor Value'].plot()
```

`pandas` will then take care to plot it nicely for you:

[image]

my Dataframe looks like this:

```
                      Datetime  Sensor Value
0     2017/02/17  19:06:17.188             2
1     2017/02/17  19:06:22.360            72
2     2017/02/17  19:06:27.348            72
3     2017/02/17  19:06:32.482            72
4     2017/02/17  19:06:37.515            74
5     2017/02/17  19:06:42.580            70
```

Comment: i am trying the pandas way. It is giving error on 'Use' that 'Python 3.5 does not support backquotes'. Whats the solution for this?

Comment: its giving error now that 'unresolved reference to Use' and also same error for to_datetime() ,set_index and DataFrame.plot().

Comment: sorry for that. Now, it gives the error:  Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>. I think I am missing some basic thing here as i am really a newbie in python.

Comment: I can only help you if you give me a sample of your dataframe

Comment: I have added the sample of dataframe in the original question.

Comment: I'm sorry, accidentally added in your answer. you can see it there.

Comment: It seems to work with the code that i have provided. Sorry

Comment: can you provide me with the full working code for this dataframe?

Comment: its okay, just give me the code, i'll check it myself.

Comment: its in the answer. the full code. you convert the column to datetime, set the index and plot